# Using a HTTPS Resource in Yahoo Pipes?

Tags: http, https, yahoo-pipes

Is possible to use a HTTPS:  resource in a URLBuilder in Yahoo Pipes?

I have used a HTTP: easily, but when I change it to HTTPS: I get an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are currently stuck. As of 2/09/09 at least, [Yahoo Pipes does not support https](http://discuss.pipes.yahoo.com/Message_Boards_for_Pipes/threadview?bn=pip-DeveloperHelp&tid=7376&mid=7377).

There is the possibility of setting up your own proxy server to do the SSL fetching for you and re-serve the content over http, but it's not something I've ever tried.

Comment: see my answer below for an easy way to make yahoo pipes work with https.

Answer (score 10):

you can work around yahoo pipes not supporting https by "proxying" your https url through [YQL (Yahoo! Query Language)](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql), which does support https. yahoo pipes has the Sources > YQL module, which you can pass a https url with a YQL query like that:

```
select * from rss where url='https://example.com/example.rss'
```

with this query, the YQL module will return all items from the original https feed.

[via [*HTTPS, Pipes and YQL*](http://discuss.pipes.yahoo.com/Message_Boards_for_Pipes/threadview?bn=pip-genDiscuss&tid=1870&mid=-1)]

Comment: Great Thanks! A perfect answer five months later.  (although I'm not sure if it was possible back in Feb when I asked.)  I wish there was a way I could now flag this as the correct answer as it now clearly is.

Comment: as the *HTTPS, Pipes and YQL* post i'm referring to was made on 11-Dec-08, i think it was possible in feb already. never mind flagging as correct answer - i appreciate the comment and the upvote.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the approach I used.  I discovered a new tool (YQL), and resolved a problem.

Answer (score 6):

Yahoo! Pipes does not currently support HTTPS.  The way I got around this problem was to set-up a PHP page on my own webserver that would fetch the HTTPS feed and echo it over HTTP.  I then pointed the pipe at that.

This would do the job:

```
<?php
    $feed_contents = file_get_contents('https://example.com/feed.rss');
    header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml');
    echo $feed_contents;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.  It seems like that is the best workaround for now.  I wanted to accept your answer as the best, but I ran over the bounty deadline and SO automatically gave it it to another answer.  sorry.